# Горизонтальная таблица в html-css

Tags: html, css

Почему-то нигде нет информации по запросу "горизонтальная таблица" – наткнулся на [эту тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1190587/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B), и тот вариант мне почти подошёл:

```css
table.horisontal tbody, table.horisontal thead {
        display:grid;
        grid-auto-flow: column
}

    table.horisontal tr {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-rows: 1fr;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
    }

    table.horisontal td {
        border: 1px solid white;
    }
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы выравнивание высоты ячеек происходило как в таблице – каждая **строка** имеет одинаковую высоту. Здесь же выравнивание есть, но оно идёт по всей "таблице", а не каждой отдельной строке, из-за чего получается как-то так:
[image: 2]

Можно ли только средствами css сделать высоту всех ячеек строки одинаковыми? (С помощью js это очень просто делается, только вот зачем тратить лишние вычисления). csHtml вот:

```cshtml
    <table class="fa-flip-horizontal horisontal">
      
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Изображение</td>
            <td>Модель</td>
            <td>Bench</td>
            <td>Однопоточный тест</td>
            <td>Двухпоточный тест</td>
            <td>Четырёхпоточный тест</td>
            <td>Восьмипоточный тест</td>
            <td>64-х-поточный тест</td>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var CPU in Model)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            <tr>
                <td class="HWtable-image">
                    <img src="../images/Hardware/CPU/@CPU.Id;.png" onError="this.src = '../images/Hardware/CPU/placeholder.png'" style="height:@r.Next(256)px"/>
                </td>
                <td><div>@CPU.ModelName</div></td>
                <td><div>@CPU.Cores2</div></td>
                <td><div>@CPU.Cores4</div></td>
                <td><div>@CPU.Cores8</div></td>
                <td><div>@CPU.Cores64</div></td>
            </tr>
        }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Можно изменить структуру html, но она должна оставаться такой, чтобы всегда можно было добавить ещё один столбец, не перезаписывая всю таблицу. Таблица должна быть прокручиваемой (по горизонтали). Я пытался "играться" с grid и flex, но самый удачный вариант вы можете видеть выше

Comment: Высота и так будет высчитываться одинаково для каждой строки, у table по умолчанию такая возможность имеется, поэтому и зовётся "ТАБЛИЦА". Поэтому не нужно всякие display: grid-ы ставить, так вы только портите таблицу

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте написать:
`tr{ height: значение; }`
если не помогло, пишите

Comment: -_-   Это не подходит, высота должна вычисляться автоматически

Answer (score 0):

```css
table.horisontal td {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<table class="fa-flip-horizontal horisontal">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Изображение</td>
      <td class="HWtable-image">
        <img src="#" style="height:@r.Next(256)px" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Модель</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.ModelName</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bench</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Однопоточный тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.Cores1</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Двухпоточный тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.Cores2</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Четырёхпоточный тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.Cores4</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Восьмипоточный тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.Cores8</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>64-х-поточный тест</td>
      <td>
        <div>@CPU.Cores64</div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `Можно изменить структуру html, но она должна оставаться такой, чтобы всегда можно было добавить ещё один столбец, не перезаписывая всю таблицу` – вот попробуй представить, как я в твой код буду добавлять ещё один столбец, не перезаписывая таблицу